# Sqlite union and sort order

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, union

```
select 'none', '0'
union
select * from category where id='2'
```

Can I retrieve the output of above sqlite query as 'none' should always be the first item ?,    ie I want to block from a combined sort of two resultsets. plz help...

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Do your category table have exactly 2 columns ?

Comment: select 'none', '0' union select 'a', '1' union select 'b', '2' - consider this query i want the result set as 'none' should be the first item

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from
(
select 'none' as col1, '0' as col2 union  select  * from category where id='2' 
) t
order by case when col1='none' then 0 else 1 end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid using `SELECT *` in a union query

```
SELECT 'none', '0', 0 AS sort
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, 1 AS sort
FROM category
WHERE id = '2'
ORDER BY sort ASC
```

Comment: thanks Phil,but an additional column generated 'sort' in resultset

Comment: @SreejithG and this is a problem, why?